# Image Captions with CSS

Tags: css, class, html, icons

I am making a simple little web based control panel of sorts, and my lack of CSS knowledge is killing me. I basically need to make a div class that uses both an image icon and places a text caption underneath it (both are links to the target page).

I found some examples for doing this on various sites, but none of them work for placing the icon/captions side by side. To give a better idea of what I am trying to do, CPanel is a perfect example of what I am trying to accomplish.

How can I go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the HTML/CSS for this site?

Comment: Why not just embed image and caption in a borderless table?

Comment: Use the browser web inspector in Chrome, Safari or Firebug in Firefox to see how it was set up.

Comment: That is just an image, I don't think I can actually access their CPanel...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
<div class="image-caption">
    Some Text
</div>

.image-caption {
    background: url(icon_path) no-repeat top center;
    width: icon_width;
    padding-top: icon_height;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that should work but is there any way to make it more..."template" style, where the image/caption/link can be specified from the HTML, and the CSS just lays it out?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Like a `caption` tag? Or having it display inline like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/sMDHS/](http://jsfiddle.net/sMDHS/)?

Comment: Sort of like that link, but I found a good one finally. Going to post it up as the answer. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Found a website with a very simplistic approach that works perfectly here...

http://www.spartanicus.utvinternet.ie/centered_image_gallery_with_captions.htm